# UIPickerView Scrolling Can cause crash with no error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

Im using a picker view which seems to work but on occasion triggers a stack trace crash with no error for me to work with.

Here is my picker view setup, it works just fine, however at total random, it can crash the app.

Any ideas as to what could be the cause?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
                return 1;
            }

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
                return _pickerChannels.count;
            }

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
                UILabel *labelSelected = (UILabel*)[_channelPickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:component];
                [labelSelected setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                self.channelGroupValue = [_pickerChannels indexOfObject:_pickerChannels[row]];
                [[self delegate] sideBarDidScrollChannels:self.channelGroupValue];
                [[self delegate] sideBarDidSetScrollChannels:self.channelGroupValue];
            }

- (UIView *) pickerView: (UIPickerView *) pickerView viewForRow: (NSInteger) row forComponent: (NSInteger) component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
        UILabel *label = (id)view;
        if (!label)
        {
            label= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [_channelPickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width,
                                                                         [_channelPickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]];
            label.text = _pickerChannels[row];
        }
        return label;
    }
```

This is the only info i can provide on the crashing:

[image]

Comment: show your crash logs

Comment: which part? its all just a jumble of text...nothing in the debugger

Comment: label.text = _pickerChannels[component]; try using this instead of this label.text = _pickerChannels[row];

Comment: that wouldnt make sense as the component is always 1, but row has to change dynamically with the array position shown

Comment: From the screenshot, it's not obvious how the picker is causing the crash. Looks like setTCPWrite: causes the crash.

Comment: ok that may be the case, just it happens from using the pickerview so wasnt sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the crash is about `CDCControl setTCPWrite` which occasionally occurs because you are using multithread, as you can see on your stack. 
To be more specified, maybe there are two threads calling `CDCControl setTCPWrite` at the same time.

Comment: any idea how i can narrow this down? its to do with my network communication (app is a remote) and ive seen this crash occur a few times when rapid messages transfer (for example the rows spinning through the uipickerview)

Comment: Do you send internet request in  `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component`? Maybe you can add NSLock in the delegate method or  before`[CDCControl setTCPWrite]`

Answer (score 0):

If your `pickerChannels` array is dynamic, I mean if it is changing it's value with other operations and if it become nil then it is possible to crash.

Second thing why you are doing,

```
  UILabel *label = (id)view;
```

if your view is label then you can do like,

```
  UILabel *label = (UILabel*)view;
```

`viewForRow` method returns `UIView`, so you should return `UIView`!! you can add label to one `UIVIew` and can return that `view`!

Comment: Thanks ive made the label change, as for the array. it isnt changing its a fixed number of strings its scrolling around. its still crashing with the label change so that isnt it! updated the OP with a screenshot